# call recorder for Moto G - clear opponents voice

Tags: applications, motorola-moto-g, call-recording

Moto G 4G
android 4.4.4

I have tried many call recorders with different settings, and in all cases my voice is clear but not the one of the opponent, the person I talk to.

Any app and settings that can register clearly the opponent s voice for Moto G?

Answer (score 2):

Good news also. Boldbeast Call recorder works perfectly for Moto G / Moto X, it records calls loudly and clearly in two directions. Root is needed.

Here is the app: [Moto G / Moto X Call Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.boldbeast.recorder)

This app is free.

Answer (score 0):

Good news first.  There is one that works.  It is called 'Call Recorder' and is by 'skvalex'.

Here is the link: [Call Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skvalex.callrecorder)

Bad news last.  It's the only one that is known to work, and it costs $9.95.